# Have pandas produce error when multiplying with nan

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'd like to have pandas produce an error when trying to do arithmetic involving cells with nan values. So if I create a dummy DataFrame:

```
test_input = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c'],
                          index=[1,2],
                          data=[[np.nan, np.nan, 2.0],[np.nan, 1.0, 3.0]])
```

which looks like this:

[image]

If I then multiply this by some other set of values, it multiplies the valid entries in the DataFrame and just leaves the NaNs as they are:

```
test_input * np.array([2,2,2])
```

[image]

Whereas I'd like it to produce an error whenever it tries to do arithmetic on a cell containing an NaN.

I've tried using .fillna to replace the NaNs with `None` (so far as I can see, can't be done because fillna thinks you've entered no value) and replacing the NaNs with strings (which produces an error if you try to multiply by a float, but not an int), but I was wondering if there was some more obvious method that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want it to produce an error when `NaN` is present?

Comment: What kind of error message should that be? One for the whole dataframe? For each row? For each cell? The NaN in your dataframe is the error message.

Comment: @Mr.T - I hadn't though about this but maybe the best way here is for me to check if the df contains NaNs and then raise the error myself if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NaN` values are of type `float`. As such, they work fine with arithmetic operations in Pandas / NumPy. You would have to override Pandas / NumPy methods to achieve your goal. **This is not recommended.**

Instead, just perform an explicit check before your computation:

```
assert test_input.notnull().values.all()  # AssertionError if null value exists
```

Comment: Yes - that's the correct thing to do here isn't it. Thanks.

Comment: I think you're missing a `not`. Also, depending on what you're using this check for, `assert` may be the wrong tool.

Comment: @user2357112, thanks, fixed that issue, I actually use `notnull` instead.. Yes, of course you can raise `ValueError` with an `if` statement, but this depends on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a built-in way to do that, and I'm not even sure if your intentions make sense.

However, you can define your own multiply function and just raise errors if there are any nulls in your data frame.

```
def mul(df, n):
    if df.isnull().any().any(): raise ValueError('Error - Custom Message')
    return df*n
```

And use as

```
mul(df, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, I think that's best.